# why does the second print statement get a return value from the void function?

Tags: c, void

I cannot find the answer to this in my book anywhere.  the second printf statement prints x: 75 y: 0 and I cannot figure out why. please help

```
#include<stdio.h>

Int scaleBack(int);
Void setValues(int*, int*, int);

Int main()
{
    Int x = 75;
    Int y = 17;
    Int factor;

    Factor = scaleBack(x / y);
    setValues(&x, &y, factor);

    printf(“factor: %d\n”, factor);
    printf(“x: %d y: %d\n”, x, y);

    return(0);
}

Int scaleBack(int quotient)
{
    Int fact;

    Fact = (quotient + 2) % (quotient + 1);

    Return(fact);
}

Void setValues(int *ax, int *ay, int factor)
{
    *ax = *ax * factor;
    *ay = *ay * (1 – factor);
}
```

Comment: Your in the land of undefined behaviour so anything can happen. You are just lucky?!

Comment: @EdHeal Where do you see UB?

Comment: this is not my code, it was on the study guide and I typed it in.  I feel like a value should not be returned but there has to be a reason as to why a value is returned.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - The printf expecting two integers and not finding them. As EdS mentions I also do not think it even compiles

Comment: Darn - The question has been edited. Still does not compile with all those caps

Comment: @user3357999 - Post code that compiles

Comment: Non-compiling code - Please fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`factor` will be 1: `x/y` is 75/17, which is 4. You call `scaleBack(4)`, which computes (4+2)%(4+1) = 6%5 = 1.

Then, later, `setValues()` will set `y` to 0 because of this:

```
*ay = *ay * (1 – factor);
```

Because `1-factor` is zero. Since `ay` points to y, `y` gets the value 0. `x` stays untouched because `setValues` multiplied it by 1.

`setValues` is not returning, but it is manipulating local variables from `main()` because you passed it pointers to `x` and `y`. Thus, the modifications done to `*ax` and to `*ay` are visible outside of `setValues`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `(quotient + 2) % (quotient + 1)` is 1 for every positive value of `quotient`.

So your call to function `scaleBack` returns 1, and your call to function `setValues` sets `y` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

After this code

```
Factor = scaleBack(x / y);
```

value of Factor is 1

You are passing (75, 17, 1) to `setValues` routine. Hence the statement

```
*ay = *ay * (1 – factor);
```

will resolve to *ay = 17 * (1 - 1) which is 0

Value of *ay will be 0